# Counting the number of elements of order $p$ in an abelian group if $p$ divides the order of the group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

If $G$ is abelian, then the Sylow $p$-subgroups are unique, right (because they're normal)?

That should give the number of elements of order $p$ equal to $n_p(p-1)=p-1$. But that's the wrong answer. Can someone tell me/explain why?

For example, in $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^3$ the number of elements of order $p=2$ is $7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The Sylow subgroup may not be cyclic (as in your example).

Noncyclic groups of order $p^n$ have more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

Try $V_4$:  three elements of order $2$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the formula $n_p(p-1)$ wasn't good for when the group wasn't cyclic. I don't follow why should that be so just because it isn't cyclic. I guess I'm not seeing it yet.

Comment: In the case of $V_4$ I can do this: $V_4 \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Finding elements of order $2$ requires that I find pairs $(g_1, g_2)$ such that $\mathrm{lcm}(|g_1|, |g_2|)=2$. We have $2^{2}$ choices for the ordered pairs, but have to exclude $1$ (the identity).

Comment: Right.   Umm, when $G$ of order $p^n$ is indeed cyclic,  it has a unique subgroup of each order $p^m$ dividing its order.   And then $\varphi (p^m)=p^m-p^{m-1}$ elements of order $p^m$.  But as the Klein four group shows,  this breaks down when $G$ is not cyclic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.